# Generically comparing objects in an inheritance hierarchy in c++

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, generic-programming

I am planning to write a multimap like this

```
std::multimap <key, base_ptr> mymap;
```

And I would like to be able to store pointers of many derived classes (say `Der1`, `Der2`) which derive from the base.

Now when I am trying to insert an object into the map, I first do a lookup on the key and then I need to compare if the object is EQUIVALENT (does not have to be the same object hence not doing a pointer comparison) to the one at that location. So for this lets say I override the `== operator` or write some kind of a compare function. Now I would like to write the code for this in such a manner that when new derived classes are added, I dont have to change or add anything.

So I am thinking there has to be a generic way of writing this. But not able to think of one.

I was thinking of something like the following

```
class Base
{
    virtual Base * get() { return this; }

    virtual bool isEqual(const Base& toObj) {
        ....
    }
}

class Der1
{
    Der1 * get() { return this; }

    bool isEqual(const Der1& toObj) {
        ....
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work either. because when I do:

```
Base* bp1;
Base* bp2;
bp1->get()->isEqual(*(bp2->get()))
```

I see that the call to `get()` does end up in the `get()` of the derived class as I expect, but then the compiler treats the returned value as `Base*`. This is most likely because its a run-time polymorphism. But I find it hard to believe that there wont be an elegant and obvious way to do this.

Can somebody advise.

Comment: `bool isEqual(const Der1& toObj)` is NOT overriding `virtual bool isEqual(const Base& toObj)` since it has a different signature!

Comment: I'd do a type check first and if the type is different => not equal, otherwise do an equality comparison on the two equal derived types.

Comment: Also note that `Der1 * get()` is NOT overriding `virtual Base * get()` for the same reason

Comment: @Onur: Actually, `Der1::get` does override `Base::get`, since the parameters match and the return types are covariant. You're right that `isEqual` doesn't override, since the parameters don't match.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You're absolutely right. But the `get()` method isn't useful anyway since you can always use `x` instead of `x.get()`.

Comment: Right I was planning to add a check using typeid as a first step. But can you explain why get() method isnt useful? Is it not true that using the get() you now have a pointer to derived class (equivalent of dynamic casting without having to hardcode the class name in the source code) because of run-time polymorphism?

Comment: on isEqual you are right i dont really need to make it virtual as what I want is for it to be not virtual but just a function that would override (hide) the base class one.

Comment: If you use get via a base pointer, the static type will still be `Base*`, even if the pointer is indeed a `Der1`. So you are not getting more (static) type information using the `get` method. If you think about it, how could you get more static information from a method which return type depends on runtime information?

Comment: `isEqual` needs to be virtual. Otherwise you cannot check if they are equal when they have the same type. How could base perform that?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
class Base
{
    public:

    // derived classes must implement this.
    // the implementation is always the same code
    virtual type_info getType() const = 0;

    virtual bool isEqual(const Base& toObj) = 0;
}

class Der1 : Base
{
    public:
    type_info getType() const { return typeid (this); }

    bool isEqual(const Base& toObj)
    {
        if (this.getType() == toObj.getType())
        {
            // we have 2 instances of Der1!
            // do comparison here
        }
        else
        {
            // the other one is no Der1 => we are not equal
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Der2 : Base
{
    public:
    type_info getType() const { return typeid (this); }

    bool isEqual(const Base& toObj)
    {
        if (this.getType() == toObj.getType())
        {
            // we have 2 instances of Der2!
            // do comparison here
        }
        else
        {
            // the other one is no Der1 => we are not equal
            return false;
        }
    }
}



void MyFunc()
{
    Base* bp1;
    Base* bp2;
    // ...
    // this should work now (although I have not tested it!)
    bool theyAreEqual = bp1->isEqual(*bp2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An equivalence relation is not appropriate. `std::multimap` and all ordered associative containers need an ordering relation. So if this a strict requirement, you should use an unordered container, that is, [unordered_multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap).

In either case, you need to provide a function object that takes two `Base*` arguments `a,b` and returns a `bool` that says whether `a<b` or `a==b` according to your definition.

Unfortunately, C++ permits run-time lookup for virtual methods only for one type at a time, and here you have two. One way over this limitation is the [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) method. This way, the generic two-argument function object

```
struct eq
{
    bool operator()(const Base& a, const Base& b)
    {
        return a.isEqual(b);
    }
};
```

will end up calling the right `isEqual` of one of the two objects, e.g. the definition of `Der1` if `a` is of this type. Now in `Der1`, the general definition would be

```
bool isEqual(const Base& x) { return x.isEqual(*this); }
```

Unfortunately at this point you would have to define several overloaded methods in each derived class e.g. `isEqual(const Der1&)`, `isEqual(const Der&)` etc.

```
class Der1
{
    // ...

    bool isEqual(const Base& x) { return x.isEqual(*this); }
    bool isEqual(const Der1& x) { ... }
    bool isEqual(const Der2& x) { ... }
    bool isEqual(const Der3& x) { ... }
};
```

Note that only the first `isEqual` above is virtual and overrides `Base`'s method. The rest are non-virtual overloads and the call `x.isEqual(*this)` will find the appropriate one because when `*this` is of type `Der2&` then `isEqual(const Der2& x)` will be preferred over `isEqual(const Base& x)` (and the remaining overloads of course).

This will work smoothly without the need for any `dynamic_cast` or constly run-time `if` or `switch` statements. However, for `n` derived classes you need `n * (n+1)` definitions of `isEqual` in the worst case (except if you exploit common patterns in the hierarchy and make savings).

Also, this approach defeats your requirement that "when new derived classes are added, I dont have to change or add anything". Then again, I don't know how you'd expect not to change anything - how would you compare a new derived type?

In am sorry I don't know any really more elegant solution. In general I prefer static polymorphism when possible but here you need a container of items of a single type so this does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, read the comments on this code:

```
class Dervived;
class Base
{
public:
    /* Note:
     * You can get rid of those functions and use dynamic_cast instead
     * which might be better.  See down for example.  */
    const Base *getBase() const { return this; }
    virtual const Dervived *getDervived() const { return NULL; }

    virtual bool operator==(const Base& other) const
    {
        printf("base call\n");
    }
};

class Dervived : public Base
{
public:
    const Dervived *getDervived() const { return this; }

    bool operator==(const Base& other) const
    {
            // case Base to Dervived here, either with dynamic_cast or C-style cast, but since you're very sure that other is Dervived, you can go for static_cast right away and no need to check for cast success.
        printf("dervive call\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Dervived();
    Base *b2 = new Dervived();

    if (*b == *b2);     // calls Dervived::operator==
        // ...

    /* An alternative way of casting:  */
    const Dervived *d = dynamic_cast<Dervived *>(b);
    if (d);
        // cast successfull
    /* Or use the members.  */
    d = b->getDervived();
    if (d);
}
```

I prefer the dynamic_cast way, however, the functions you made are quite useless, but i prefer to use these kind of functions sometimes like so:

```
class Base
{
...
virtual bool isDervived() const { return false; }
};

class Dervived
{
...
bool isDervived() const { return true; }
};
```

**Note** You shouldn't need to compare before casting, at least this is what I would do.

Comment: How would this scale to an unknown number of derived classes?

Comment: @Onur how wouldnt it? it's as simple as creating the first one.

Comment: How would you compare `Derived` and `OtherDerived` without `Derived` knowing of the existence of `OtherDerived`?

Comment: Sounds stupid, you know your own code design, do it based on it?

Comment: It's not my code since it's not my question ;-). I was just curious about the intentions for your design. There's always something to learn...

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive.  what I meant was that you shall never be in need of such thing, however, if you really want to make stuff more transparent I would go with `getClassName()` virtual method or with the boolean ones I explained.

Comment: I agree that one should aim for a different design instead of trying to find a working implementation. My solution is similar to your `getClassName()` approach by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch):

Following may help (require C++11): http://ideone.com/lTsc7M

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

/////////////////////////

#if 1 // multiple dispatch

// sequence of size_t // not in C++11
template <std::size_t ...> struct index_sequence {};

// Create index_sequence<0, >
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence <N - 1, N - 1, Is... > {};

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};

// Generic IVisitor
// Do: using MyIVisitor = IVisitorTs<Child1, Child2, ...>
template <typename ... Ts> class IVisitorTs;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
class IVisitorTs<T, Ts...> : public IVisitorTs<Ts...>
{
public:
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
    using IVisitorTs<Ts...>::visit;

    virtual void visit(const T& t) = 0;
};

template <typename T> class IVisitorTs<T>
{
public:
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<T>;

    virtual void visit(const T& t) = 0;
};

namespace detail {

// retrieve the index of T in Ts...
template <typename T, typename ... Ts> struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename Tail,  typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, Tail, Ts...> :
        std::integral_constant < std::size_t, 1 + get_index<T, Ts...>::value > {};

// retrieve the index of T in Tuple<Ts...>
template <typename T, typename Tuple> struct get_index_in_tuple;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct get_index_in_tuple<T, C<Ts...>> : get_index<T, Ts...> {};

// get element of a multiarray
template <std::size_t I>
struct multi_array_getter
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    static constexpr auto get(const T& a, const std::array<std::size_t, N>& index)
    -> decltype(multi_array_getter<I - 1>::get(a[index[N - I]], index))
    {
        return multi_array_getter<I - 1>::get(a[index[N - I]], index);
    }
};

template <>
struct multi_array_getter<0>
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    static constexpr auto get(const T& a, const std::array<std::size_t, N>& index)
    -> decltype(a)
    {
        return a;
    }
};

// Provide an implementation of visitor
// by forwarding to C implementation (which may be non virtual)
template <typename IVisitor, typename C, typename...Ts> struct IVisitorImpl;

template <typename IVisitor, typename C, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct IVisitorImpl<IVisitor, C, T, Ts...> : IVisitorImpl<IVisitor, C, Ts...>
{
    virtual void visit(const T& t) override { C::visit(t); }
};

template <typename IVisitor, typename C, typename T>
struct IVisitorImpl<IVisitor, C, T> : IVisitor, C
{
    virtual void visit(const T& t) override { C::visit(t); }
};

// helper to expand child type to IVisitorImpl
template <typename IVisitor, typename C>
struct IVisitorImplType;

template <typename ... Ts, typename C>
struct IVisitorImplType<IVisitorTs<Ts...>, C>
{
    using type = IVisitorImpl<IVisitorTs<Ts...>, C, Ts...>;
};

// Create an multi array of pointer of function
// (with all combinaisons of overload).
template <typename Ret, typename F, typename Arg>
class GetAllOverload
{
private:
    template <typename...Ts>
    struct Functor
    {
        // function which will be in array.
        static Ret call(F&f, const Arg& arg)
        {
            return call_helper(f, arg, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
        }
    private:
        // The final dispatched function
        template <std::size_t ... Is>
        static Ret call_helper(F&f, const Arg& arg, index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            using RetTuple = std::tuple<Ts&...>;
            // static cast is suffisant if arg is the abstract type
            // when given arg is concrete type, reinterpret_cast is required.
            // TODO: build a smaller table with only possible value to avoid that
            return f(reinterpret_cast<typename std::tuple_element<Is, RetTuple>::type>(std::get<Is>(arg))...);
        }
    };

    // helper class to create the multi array of function pointer
    template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename...Ts>
    struct Builder;

    template <typename...Ts, typename...Ts2>
    struct Builder<1, std::tuple<Ts...>, Ts2...>
    {
        using RetType = std::array<Ret (*)(F&, const Arg&), sizeof...(Ts)>;

        static constexpr RetType build()
        {
            return RetType{ &Functor<Ts2..., Ts>::call... };
        }
    };

    template <std::size_t N, typename ...Ts, typename...Ts2>
    struct Builder<N, std::tuple<Ts...>, Ts2...>
    {
        template <typename T>
        using RecType = Builder<N - 1, std::tuple<Ts...>, Ts2..., T>;
        using T0 = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
        using RetType = std::array<decltype(RecType<T0>::build()), sizeof...(Ts)>;

        static constexpr RetType build() {
            return RetType{ RecType<Ts>::build()... };
        }
    };

public:
    template <std::size_t N, typename VisitorTuple>
    static constexpr auto get()
    -> decltype(Builder<N, VisitorTuple>::build())
    {
        return Builder<N, VisitorTuple>::build();
    }
};

template <typename Ret, typename IVisitor, typename F, std::size_t N>
class dispatcher
{
private:
    std::array<std::size_t, N> index;

    struct visitorCallImpl
    {
        template <typename T>
        void visit(const T&) const
        {
            *index = get_index_in_tuple<T, IVisitor>::value;
        }

        void setIndexPtr(std::size_t& index) { this->index = &index; }
    private:
        std::size_t* index = nullptr;
    };

    template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
    void set_index(const Tuple&t)
    {
        using VisitorType = typename IVisitorImplType<IVisitor, visitorCallImpl>::type;
        VisitorType visitor;
        visitor.setIndexPtr(index[I]);

        std::get<I>(t).accept(visitor);
    }
public:
    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
    Ret operator () (F&& f, const Tuple&t, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        const int dummy[] = {(set_index<Is>(t), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // silent the warning unused varaible
        constexpr auto a = GetAllOverload<Ret, F&&, Tuple>::
            template get<sizeof...(Is), typename IVisitor::tuple_type>();
        auto func = multi_array_getter<N>::get(a, index);
        return (*func)(f, t);
    }
};

} // namespace detail

template <typename Ret, typename Visitor, typename F, typename ... Ts>
Ret dispatch(F&& f, Ts&...args)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
    detail::dispatcher<Ret, Visitor, F&&, size> d;
    return d(std::forward<F>(f), std::tie(args...), make_index_sequence<size>());
}

#endif // multiple dispatch

#if 1 // multiple dispatch usage
struct Square;
struct Rect;
struct Circle;

using IShapeVisitor = IVisitorTs<Square, Rect, Circle>;

struct IShape {
    virtual ~IShape() = default;
    virtual void accept(IShapeVisitor&) const = 0;
};
struct Rect : IShape {
    virtual void accept(IShapeVisitor& v) const override { v.visit(*this); }
};

struct Square : Rect {
    virtual void accept(IShapeVisitor& v) const override { v.visit(*this); }
};
struct Circle : IShape {
    virtual void accept(IShapeVisitor& v) const override { v.visit(*this); }
};

class ShapePrinter : public IShapeVisitor
{
public:
    void visit(const Rect& s) override { std::cout << "Rect"; }
    void visit(const Square& s) override { std::cout << "Square"; }
    void visit(const Circle& s) override { std::cout << "Circle"; }
};

struct IsEqual
{
    bool operator() (IShape& s1, IShape& s2) const
    {
        ShapePrinter printer;
        s1.accept(printer);
        std::cout << " != ";
        s2.accept(printer);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    template <typename S>
    bool operator() (S& s1, S& s2) const
    {
        ShapePrinter printer;
        s1.accept(printer);
        std::cout << " == ";
        s2.accept(printer);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Rect rect;
    Square sq;
    Circle c;
    IShape* shapes[] = { &rect, &sq, &c };

    for (auto shape1 : shapes) {
        for (auto shape2 : shapes) {
            dispatch<bool, IShapeVisitor>(IsEqual(), *shape1, *shape2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#endif // multiple dispatch usage
```