# Overload a function with a derived class argument if you only have a pointer to the base class in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

I have seen people using containers of pointers to the base class to hold groups of objects which share the same virtual functions. Is it possible to use overloaded functions of the derived class with these base class pointers. It is hard to explain what I mean but (I think) easy to show with code

```
class PhysicsObject // A pure virtual class
{
    // Members of physics object
    // ...
};

class Circle : public PhysicsObject
{
    // Members of circle
    // ...
};

class Box : public PhysicsObject
{
    // Members of box
    // ...
};

// Overloaded functions (Defined elsewhere)
void ResolveCollision(Circle& a, Box& b);
void ResolveCollision(Circle& a, Circle& b);
void ResolveCollision(Box& a, Box& b);

int main()
{
    // Container to hold all our objects 
    std::vector<PhysicsObject*> objects;

    // Create some circles and boxes and add to objects container
    // ...

    // Resolve any collisions between colliding objects
    for (auto& objA : objects)
        for (auto& objB : objects)
            if (objA != objB)
                ResolveCollision(*objA, *objB); // !!! Error !!! Can't resolve overloaded function
}
```

My first idea was to make these functions be virtual class members also (shown below) but I quickly realised that it has exactly the same issue.

```
class Circle;
class Box;
class PhysicsObject // A pure virtual class
{
    virtual void ResolveCollision(Circle& a) = 0;
    virtual void ResolveCollision(Box& a) = 0;
    // Members of physics object
    // ...
};

class Box;
class Circle : public PhysicsObject
{
    void ResolveCollision(Circle& a);
    void ResolveCollision(Box& a);
    // Members of circle
    // ...
};

class Circle;
class Box : public PhysicsObject
{
    void ResolveCollision(Circle& a);
    void ResolveCollision(Box& a);
    // Members of box
    // ...
};
```

From googling the problem it seems like possibly it can be solved using casting but I can't figure out how to find the correct type to cast to (also it is ugly). I suspect I am asking the wrong question and there is a better way to structure my code which sidesteps this problem and achieves the same result.

Comment: Look at [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: The problem is obvious - no overload takes 2 `PhysicsObject`s as an arguments, hence the error. Either provide the overload, or use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Sure, I can create an overload that takes two PhysicsObjects but I still don't know which type of physics object they are so I have the same problem. Thanks @Jarod42, will give it a read now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With double dispatch, it would be something like:

```
class Circle;
class Box;

// Overloaded functions (Defined elsewhere)
void ResolveCollision(Circle& a, Box& b);
void ResolveCollision(Circle& a, Circle& b);
void ResolveCollision(Box& a, Box& b);
class PhysicsObject // A pure virtual class
{
public:
    virtual ~PhysicsObject() = default;

    virtual void ResolveCollision(PhysicsObject&) = 0;
    virtual void ResolveBoxCollision(Box&) = 0;
    virtual void ResolveCircleCollision(Circle&) = 0;
};

class Circle : public PhysicsObject
{
public:
    void ResolveCollision(PhysicsObject& other) override { return other.ResolveCircleCollision(*this); }
    void ResolveBoxCollision(Box& box) override { ::ResolveCollision(*this, box);}
    void ResolveCircleCollision(Circle& circle) override { ::ResolveCollision(*this, circle);}
    // ...
};

class Box : public PhysicsObject
{
public:
    void ResolveCollision(PhysicsObject& other) override { return other.ResolveBoxCollision(*this); }
    void ResolveBoxCollision(Box& box) override { ::ResolveCollision(box, *this);}
    void ResolveCircleCollision(Circle& circle) override { ::ResolveCollision(circle, *this);}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Your code clearly shows it, but just to mention it: The obvious drawback is that for `n` involved classes, every single class needs `n` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of double dispatch before but using your answer it was easy to adapt to my own code. It seems like a simple solution if you do not have too many shapes.

Comment: I have also done [Multiple dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345504/2684539), which might simplify usage (even if full implementation is more complicated).

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd do this is to build a `Extent` class that tells you about the physical perimeter of an object, perhaps with respect to its barycentre. Additionally, you'd have

`virtual const Extent& getExtent() const = 0;`

in the `PhysicsObject` class. You then implement `getExtent` once per object type.

Your collision detection line becomes

```
ResolveCollision(objA->getExtent(), objB->getExtent());
```

Although, in a sense, this does little more than kick the can down the road as the complexity is pushed to the `Extent` class, the approach will scale well since you only need to build one method per object.

The alternative double dispatch mechanism is intrusive insofar that a new shape requires adjustment to *all* existing shapes. Having to recompile the `Circle` class, for example, if you introduce an `Ellipse` class, say, is a code smell to me.

Comment: This could be the easiest approach, indeed. However, your `Extent` class might get complicated/complex if there are a number of shapes and they vary quite much. Another issue that you might run into is that you are now only working on the extent, no longer on the actual objects. As long as you just detect collision, this should be sufficient. If you want to apply forces to the objects, depending on the detected collision, or need to pass the objects to a callback that is invoked upon collision, you might need the types of (and pointers to) the actual shapes.

Comment: @nh_ but if you're smart the Extent class could take over the rendering too. And things like the moment of inertia are only a function of perimeter and barycentre (assuming uniform density), so it could do spin too.

Comment: No doubt. Just wondering how you would implement the `Extent`. Wouldn't you have to distinguish the cases of a center + diameter and box case there? And wouldn't this end up in a lot of `if(a->isCircular() && b->isCircular()) { /*...*/ } else if(a->isCircular() && b->isBox()) { /*...*/ } else ...`?

Comment: @nh_ I'd use a load of splines - a bit like the way a drawing package does. And it certainly wouldn't end up with a load of isCircular etc., else the programmer might be sent back on a coding course.

Comment: interesting. Thanks for the insight, don't have that much experience in implementing efficient collision detection. The approach you proposed is then most likely the way to go and I consider my answer as a possible solution to non-collision-detection double-dispatch problems. :)

Comment: @bathseba Thanks, interesting answer and good food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to sketch an implementation that does not rely on double-dispatch. Instead, it makes use of a table where all functions are registered. This table is then accessed using the dynamic type of the objects (passed as base class).

First, we have some example shapes. Their types are enlisted inside an `enum class`. Every shape class defines a `MY_TYPE` as their respective enum entry. Furthermore, they have to implement the base class' pure virtual `type` method:

```
enum class ObjectType
{
    Circle,
    Box,
    _Count,
};

class PhysicsObject
{
public:
    virtual ObjectType type() const = 0;
};

class Circle : public PhysicsObject
{
public:
    static const ObjectType MY_TYPE = ObjectType::Circle;

    ObjectType type() const override { return MY_TYPE; }
};

class Box : public PhysicsObject
{
public:
    static const ObjectType MY_TYPE = ObjectType::Box;

    ObjectType type() const override { return MY_TYPE; }
};
```

Next, you have your collision resolution functions, they have to be implemented depending on the shapes, of course.

```
void ResolveCircleCircle(Circle* c1, Circle* c2)
{
    std::cout << "Circle-Circle" << std::endl;
}

void ResolveCircleBox(Circle* c, Box* b)
{
    std::cout << "Circle-Box" << std::endl;
}

void ResolveBoxBox(Box* b1, Box* b2)
{
    std::cout << "Box-Box" << std::endl;
}
```

Note, that we only have `Circle`-`Box` here, no `Box`-`Circle`, as I assume their collision is detected in the same way. More on the `Box`-`Circle` collision case later.

Now to the core part, the function table:

```
std::function<void(PhysicsObject*,PhysicsObject*)>
    ResolveFunctionTable[(int)(ObjectType::_Count)][(int)(ObjectType::_Count)];
REGISTER_RESOLVE_FUNCTION(Circle, Circle, &ResolveCircleCircle);
REGISTER_RESOLVE_FUNCTION(Circle, Box, &ResolveCircleBox);
REGISTER_RESOLVE_FUNCTION(Box, Box, &ResolveBoxBox);
```

The table itself is a 2d array of `std::function`s. Note, that those functions accept pointers to `PhysicsObject`, not the derived classes. Then, we use some macros for easy registration. Of course, the respective code could be written by hand and I am quite aware of the fact that the use of macros is typically considered bad habit. However, in my opinion, these sorts of things are what macros are good for and as long as you use meaningful names that do not clutter your global namespace, they are acceptable. Notice again that only `Circle`-`Box` is registered, not the other way round.

Now to the fancy macro:

```
#define CONCAT2(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT2(x,y)

#define REGISTER_RESOLVE_FUNCTION(o1,o2,fn) \
    const bool CONCAT(__reg_, __LINE__) = []() { \
        int o1type = static_cast<int>(o1::MY_TYPE); \
        int o2type = static_cast<int>(o2::MY_TYPE); \
        assert(o1type <= o2type); \
        assert(!ResolveFunctionTable[o1type][o2type]); \
        ResolveFunctionTable[o1type][o2type] = \
            [](PhysicsObject* p1, PhysicsObject* p2) { \
                    (*fn)(static_cast<o1*>(p1), static_cast<o2*>(p2)); \
            }; \
        return true; \
    }();
```

The macro defines a uniquely named variable (using the line number), but this variable merely serves to get the code inside the initializing lambda function to be executed. The types (from the `ObjectType` enum) of the passed two arguments (these are the concrete classes `Box` and `Circle`) are taken and used to index the table. The entire mechanism assumes that there is a total order on the types (as defined in the enum) and checks that a function for `Circle`-`Box` collision is indeed registered for the arguments in this order. The `assert` tells you if you are doing it wrong (accidentally registering `Box`-`Circle`). Then a lambda function is registered inside the table for this particular pair of types. The function itself takes two arguments of type `PhysicsObject*` and casts them to the concrete types before invoking the registered function.

Next, we can have a look at how the table is then used. It is now easy to implement a single function that checks collision of any two `PhysicsObject`s:

```
void ResolveCollision(PhysicsObject* p1, PhysicsObject* p2)
{
    int p1type = static_cast<int>(p1->type());
    int p2type = static_cast<int>(p2->type());
    if(p1type > p2type) {
        std::swap(p1type, p2type);
        std::swap(p1, p2);
    }
    assert(ResolveFunctionTable[p1type][p2type]);
    ResolveFunctionTable[p1type][p2type](p1, p2);
}
```

It takes the dynamic types of the argument and passes them to the function registered for those respective types inside the `ResolveFunctionTable`. Notice, that the arguments are swapped if they are not in order. Thus you are free to invoke `ResolveCollision` with `Box` and `Circle` and it will then internally invoke the function registered for `Circle`-`Box` collision.

Lastly, I will give an example of how to use it:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Box box;
    Circle circle;

    ResolveCollision(&box, &box);
    ResolveCollision(&box, &circle);
    ResolveCollision(&circle, &box);
    ResolveCollision(&circle, &circle);
}
```

Easy, isn't it? See [this](http://cpp.sh/2r44u) for a working implementation of the above.

---

Now, what is the advantage of this approach? The above code is basically all you need to support an arbitrary number of shapes. Let's say you are about to add a `Triangle`. All you have to do is:

1. Add an entry `Triangle` to the `ObjectType` enum.
2. Implement your `ResolveTriangleXXX` functions, but you have to do this in all cases.
3. Register them to your table using the macro: `REGISTER_RESOLVE_FUNCTION(Triangle, Triangle, &ResolveTriangleTriangle);`

That's it. No need to add further methods to `PhysicsObject`, no need to implement methods in all existing types.

I am aware of some 'flaws' of this approach like using macros, having a central `enum` of all types and relying on a global table. The latter case might lead to some trouble if the shape classes are built into multiple shared libraries. However, in my humble opinion, this approach is quite practical (except for very special use cases) since it does not lead to the explosion of code as is the case with other approaches (e.g. double-dispatch).

Comment: You've put a lot of effort into this - although not the way I'd do it (my approach is much simpler IMHO) , this is clearly worth an upvote: it is a plausible solution. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate it!

Comment: @nh_ Thanks, I had foreseen the issue that it was not going to scale well when adding more shapes which your solution solves. It was hard to choose an answer since they all help in different ways.I think yours was possibly the best general answer that will help many people but the other answer was easier for me personally to implement right now. I will come back and study your answer again when I have more time since I am not very familiar with all of the concepts right now.