# function override with derived argument

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want to create a collision system, in which a base class represents an object in the scene, implements all the collision logic, and when a collision is detected, a derived class function is called for the program logic. The problem that i am facing, is that the base class needs to know about all the derived classes, for the dispatch in different functions to work correctly.

Example, base class, `OnCollisionDetected` will be overridden by the derived class to handle the collision

```
#include <iostream>

class BasePhysicsObject {
public:

    void Collides(BasePhysicsObject * another_object) {
        /* ... */
        bool collides = true;

        if (collides) this->OnCollisionDetected(another_object);
        return;
    }

    /* Function to be overriden */
    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object) = 0;
};
```

Two dummy classes in the scene, with the function `OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object)` overridden, to dispatch the call to the appropriate function based on the `this` argument.

```
class Fire;

class Player : public BasePhysicsObject {
public:

    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object) {
        /* double dispatch to specific implementation */
        another_object->OnCollisionDetected(this);
    }

    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Fire * fire) {
        /* Collision with fire object*/
    }
};

class Fire : public BasePhysicsObject {
public:

    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object) {
        /* double dispatch to specific implementation */
        another_object->OnCollisionDetected(this);
    }

    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Player * player) {
        /* Collision with player object */
    }
};
```

Main function creates two objects, and checks their collision.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    Player * player = new Player();
    Fire * fire = new Fire();

    fire->Collides(player);
}
```

What ends up happening, is that `Fire::OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object)` which is called from `Collides()` does not call the function with the derived class as argument i.e `Player::OnCollisionDetected(Fire * fire)`, but rather the `Player::OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object)` which again calls back the function, resulting in a stack overflow. 
As i am given to understand, in order for double dispatch to work, I need to declare `OnCollisionDetected(Derived *)` in the base class for all derived classes, but this is a daunting solution. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/a-polyglots-guide-to-multiple-dispatch/

Comment: Looks like `visitor` pattern to me.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thank you for the response, so if the then else is the answer for multiple dispatch?

Comment: For this approach to work, You would need `BasePhysicsObject` to have a `virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Fire *) = 0;` and `virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Player *) = 0;`. As it is, when you call `another_object->OnCollisionDetected(this);` the *only* overload that a `BasicPhysicsObject` has is `OnCollisionDetected(BasePhysicsObject * another_object)`. The derived types overloads are never taken into account. They have `virtual` members but don't override anything. Using `override` would have helped identify the problem. The general solution to this problem would be to use visitors.

Comment: You can't override a virtual method with one set of parameters using a descendant method with a different set of parameters, even if the parameter types are related. The signature of the overriding method must exactly match the method that it is overriding. Only [return values are allowed to be covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), but not parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For double dispatch pattern, you have to have a virtual dispatcher.
first dispatch is done via virtual call on lhs instance, which than does the dispatch with rhs instance:

```
class BasePhysicsObject {
public:
    virtual ~BasePhysicsObject() = default;

    virtual void CollideDispatcher(BasePhysicsObject* ) = 0;

    // The true collision code.
    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Fire*) = 0;
    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Player*) = 0;
};

class Player : public BasePhysicsObject {
public:
    // Always same implementation
    // but `this` type is different for each class
    // Which allow correct overload resolution
    void CollideDispatcher(BasePhysicsObject* rhs) override { rhs->OnCollisionDetected(this); }

    void OnCollisionDetected(Fire* rhs) override { /* Player/Fire collision */ }
    void OnCollisionDetected(Player* rhs) override { /*Player/Player collision*/ }
};

class Fire : public BasePhysicsObject {
public:
    // Always same implementation
    // but `this` type is different for each class
    // Which allow correct overload resolution
    void CollideDispatcher(BasePhysicsObject* rhs) override { rhs->OnCollisionDetected(this); }

    void OnCollisionDetected(Fire* rhs) override { /* Fire/Fire collision */ }
    virtual void OnCollisionDetected(Player* rhs) override {
         // Fire/Player collision:
         // might be symmetrical to Player/Fire collision and so:
         rhs->OnCollisionDetected(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I kinda wished there was some way to avoid declaring all the derived classes inside the base class, since in a complex scene these can be a lot, and you would have to change the base class every time you add a new derived class...

Comment: I have done a [multiple dispath visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345504/2684539) which minimizes the needed dependencies. Might be overkill for your needs.